# In Ionic 3 how do I open all links from dynamically fetched HTML in System Browser?

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am making an Ionic app based on the following [Ionic Wordpress App Template](https://codecanyon.net/item/ionic-2-app-angular-2-ionic-2-typescript-i18n-full-app/19216199) that works with the WP Rest API.

There's a page that loads a list of posts as an array of an object containing the HTML of the post as rendered by Wordpress.

#### extract of `Wordpress Service`

```
let url = this.config.wordpressApiUrl + `/wp/v2/posts?${query}&_embed`;
return this.http.get(url)
    .map(result => {
        return result.json();
    });
```

#### extract of `Wordpress Posts Component`

```
export class WordpressPosts implements OnInit {

    posts: any;
    //...
    ngOnInit() {
        this.wordpressService.getPosts()
            .subscribe(
                result => this.posts = result
            );
    }
```

That rendered HTML is then inserted into the DOM

#### extract of `Worpress Post HTML`

```
<ion-card text-wrap *ngIf="post.content.rendered">
    <p id="postContent" padding [innerHtml]="post.content.rendered"></p>
</ion-card>
```

I would like to have all the links in that `innerHTML` (`post.content.rendered`) to have their `href="(.+)"` (simplified Regex) replaced by `(click)="openLink($1)"` with the following `openLink()` function :

```
openLink(url) {
    window.open(url, '_system');
}
```

which works great for opening links in the system browser (Chrome or Safari) instead of the InAppBrowser or worse, inside the app replacing it.

In AngularJS I could have used `$compile` but since there I don't know any alternative for this in Angular 4. Is there any way to manually invoke the Angular template compiler on that HTML code before putting it on the DOM? Or is there another way to get all the links in that HTML open in the system browser?

Comment: have a look at this angular life cycle https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#aftercontent

Answer (score 3):

Adding target attribute to links should work.

```
<a target="_system" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

If it doesn't work you have two additional options without compiling Angular.

Html for both options:

```
<div #dynamic></div>
```

#### Option 1

Have an array of anchor elements and assign onclick event to all.

```
export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild('dynamic') dynamic: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let text = '<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>';

      let el = this.dynamic.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      el.innerHTML = text;
      let arrayOfLinks = el.querySelectorAll('a');;
      for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++) {
        let anchor = arrayOfLinks[i];
        anchor.onclick = function(ev) {
          window.open(anchor.href, '_system');
          ev.preventDefault();
          return false;
        };
      };
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

#### Option 2

Have a global onclick handler and assign onclick on HTML to anchor elements.

```
export class MyPage {
  @ViewChild('dynamic') dynamic: ElementRef;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let text = '<a onclick="openInNewBrowser()" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>';

      let el = this.dynamic.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
      el.innerHTML = text;
    }, 1000);
  }
```

}

Global method anywhere in your app:

```
window['openInNewBrowser'] = function () {
  let anchor = event.target;
  window.open(anchor['href'], '_system');
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried the second solution before posting here (I don't know if it would change something if I do it via jQuery) I added the JS in a `script` tag surrounded with `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... } );` it's not working, the links keep getting opened inside my Ionic App or in an InAppBrowser and not with the System Browser

Comment: Why is compiling the Angular Template dynamically a bad practice ? Isn't it way cleaner than simply injecting HTML code that comes from a server inside a target div bypassing completely the Angular Template Engine ? Please if there is a way to `$compile()` some HTML before injecting it into a `div` that's exactly the kind of solutions I'm after

Comment: @KiJéy I don't know if it is a bad practice but you would have to probably include Angular compiler in your app. Which would grow your app size. I thought your situation is too trivial to go with that solution. As to why the solution didn't work, are you sure window load script runs? Because it should only run when the page loads. Not a sub DOM tree.

Comment: I have updated my question for more clarity. Also, could you explain to me a bit more your solution that uses `@HostListener` ? Where should I put that code ? Thanks

Comment: @KiJéy `(click)` is an Angular thing, as my directive is. Your template needs to be compiled by Angular to have Angular things work. I don't know an easy way to do that. But instead of `(click)`, you can use `onclick` which is a pure HTML attribute, with a global function like: `function openLink() { window.open(event.target.href, '_system'); return false; }`

Comment: I got that. I tried using `onclick` but for some reason it doesn't work on mobile device. I think it has something to do with the need for the function to be called by Angular in order to trigger native functions from the cordova plugin

Comment: Can you please join a working plunkr ? What I tried to explain earlier is that the function called on click on a link needs to be a function from the Angular Controller even if it's only `window.open()` or it doesn't work on the compiled app because it wont call the cordova plugin

Answer (score 0):

how about you use a `DOMParser` which is an experimental WebApi. You can parse the html and then push it to view (maybe in `NgZone`). You can find the basic example in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "text/html");
```

and then extract the anchor tags:

```
let aElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (let i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
  console.log(aElements[i].innerHTML);
}
```

So basically once you have access to `a` elements then you can change its attributes.
E.g to attach a press event (you have to try on click event, i have only tried press from component), follow:

```
for (let i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
      this.pressGesture = new Gesture(aElements[i].innerHtml);
        this.pressGesture.listen();
        this.pressGesture.on('press', e => { 
            console.log('testing');
        });
}
```

You have to play around with code, i havn't tested this code but it should work. Using gesture, you can bind any native event. Check this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NL1rDMeXsuc). 
 
Other option would be to create global event listener and open the link in system browser. But to work around iOS, you will need to use InAppBrowser.
Install [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/Prasannaa1991/cordova-inappbrowser), and use the following code in `index.html`

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
          if(event.srcElement.target == '_system' || event.srcElement.target == '_blank') {
              var url = this.href;
              window.open(url,"_system");
          }
  });
```

Comment: How would that help ?

Comment: I can already access all `a` elements, the question is how can I add an Angular `(click)` attribute that is able to call a function defined in the controller ?

Comment: @KiJéy check my updated answer. Using gesture, you can bind the event.

Comment: The problem is that just adding `target="_system"` on the links doesn't work. I tried that already via regExp before injecting the code in my target `div` I need to call a function defined in the controller via `(click)` (Angular2's ng-click)

Comment: @KiJéy defined this code in global file i.e `index.html`. i tried this and it worked for me but i tried it in ionic 1 project. As its JavaScript so it should be the same for ionic 2 or 3. It would be helpful to make a demo project and share it on github or jsfiddle

Comment: I have updated my question for more clarity about my specific problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs has jquery inbuilt, so can you try to attach an event handler like below

```
$('a').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var link = $(this).attr('href');
  window.open('link');
});
```

you can attach it after you embed html in ajax callback or even in init.

Comment: Yes but I forgot to ask if you are importing jquery in your project, otherwise you can write the same in pure javascript too.

Comment: this won't work for dynamic elements, as `a` are added later...you need event delegates...